# How can I find a tag inside a document in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to find out if the document -which is an html file- has "some" tags. If so, I want to get all its attributes.

I tried

```
var data = require('test.html');
if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf('<iframe') > -1|| data.toLowerCase().indexOf('<iframe>') > -1){
 console.log('yeaaah it exist'); 

 // get iframe attributes
}
```

I was able to find if the tag exist, but how can I get its attributes?
Also this is on server side.

Comment: Hint: what does the indexOf() method return when a string isn't found?

Comment: i just made chances to the code.. for some reasons it returns false if indexOf() matches the string.... so i simply use '!'.. Now iam able to determine that the tag exist.. How do i get its arrtibutes?

Comment: No, indexOf() doesn't return true or false, it returns a number. Using ! doesn't really fix the problem, it just seems that way because you didn't test all the possibilities.

Comment: yes your are right... @Daniel Its on server side.

Comment: what do you mean by server side? nodejs?

Comment: Yes. I am working on nodejs

Comment: You can't require `html` files like that then. You'll need to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it done using Cheerio

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var url = "./test.html";  // if it does not work try with absolute url
download(url, function(data) {
if (data) {
// console.log(data);
var TestData = cheerio.load(data);
// to get the tag simply use TestData("sometag")
console.log(TestData("sometag").length);
 }
});
```